# Convert Access query to SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ms-access

I am converting `Access` query to `SQL Server`.

I want to convert below lines to SQL

```
1. Format (210.6, "Standard")
2. Format (210.6, "#,##0.00")
```

How do i convert it to SQL query.

I have tried with below, but still not able to find the solution.

For the first query, i found below solution, which is correct

```
    1. CONVERT(varchar, CAST(tSRO.OutputF11 AS money), 1)
```

Now, for second query, i do not know what i have to do.

Comment: Share how results should look like

Comment: Result for first query should be Result: '210.60' and for second query Result: '210.60'

Comment: And for `1210.6` => `1,210.60`?

Comment: Please avoid crossposting

Comment: Okay, i will keep this in mind next time

Comment: @lad2025 yes, exactly

Answer (score 2):

From **SQL Server 2012+** you can use `FORMAT`:

```
SELECT FORMAT(210.6, '#,##0.00')  -- 210.60

SELECT FORMAT(1210.6, '#,##0.00')  -- 1,210.60
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/380118)**</kbd>

SQL Server before 2012:

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR,CONVERT(MONEY, 1210.6),1),'.00','')  -- 1,210.60
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo2`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/380121)**</kbd>

*Warning:*

This operation is pure for presentation layer and should be done in application.

Comment: I have tried it in my environment and it is lower version. so that's why it is not working

Comment: what if i have a lower version?

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: Although this solution will work, formatting data for display purposes is better done in the presentation layer rather than SQL.  This practice improves database performance and leverages front-end formatting capabilities that are generally more robust.

Comment: @DanGuzman As always it depends. You are right that this is pure presentation task. But it is so common that most RDBMS support multiple formating functions. For example application with simple data grid that does not do any changes and only show what it retrieves from DB.

Comment: @lad2025, It doesn't matter of the RDMBS provides formatting capabilities or not.  I'm just suggesting the best practice is presentation layer formatting.  You are right that `it depends` but the only overarching reason to do formatting in SQL is initial porting of a legacy application.  That may apply here but I just want to caution it's not proper development practice for new development.